# Define class constant with other constant from the same class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, constants

I am trying to create a class with multiple constants (in Python 3.6). Because the constants are lists and dictionaries with a lot of correlated values I want to generate some constants using the others.

While trying to do so I stumbled upon some limitations which I don't fully understand. I will show this in the following examples:

Class `Example1` is created without errors:

```
class Example1:  # this works
    C1 = [1, 2, 3]
    C2 = [2, 3, 4]
    C3 = [C2, C2]
    C4 = [C1[0], C2[2]]
    C5 = [str(c1) for c1 in C1]
    C6 = [c1 + c2 for c1, c2 in zip(C1, C2)]
```

However trying to create `Example2`:

```
class Example2:  # this doesn't work
    C1 = 1
    C2 = [1, 2, 3]
    C3 = [C1 + c2 for c2 in C2]
```

raises `NameError: name 'C1' is not defined` while trying to create `C3`.

The same happens with `Example3`:

```
class Example3:  # this doesn't work
    C1 = [1, 2, 3]
    C2 = [2, 3, 4]
    C3 = [c1 + c2 for c2 in C2 for c1 in C1]
```

Can someone provide an explanation why `Example2` and `Example3` don't work but `Example1` does? What are the rules here? Is there any alternative way to initialize constant `C3` in `Example2` and `Example3` inside the class?

P.S. Sorry for asking multiple subquestions.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. I managed to find alternatives to `Example2` and `Example3` using lambda function or using `itertools`.